# the way of editing file in openerp

Tags: odoo

I want to ask about editing files in OpenERP, especially in v7.

I edit XML file (form, tree, search) is from frontend XML inside OpenERP; I edit python file is from backend of OpenERP folder in .py file; I edit XML file (action) is from database (model) OpenERP not from frontend XML inside OpenERP; etc.

The question: does the way that I mention above is the only way in editing it? Is it any other simple way? If I must edit the file from many place (XML, .py, database(model),etc ), I think this is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To edit a OpenERP file manually, its bit easier to edit file in Eclipse IDE,
there are templates available for OpenERP in Eclipse IDE that will help you to edit file faster then any other editor.

This is the link of the [OpenERP template for Eclipse IDE](http://code.google.com/p/openerp-eclipse-template/). if you face any issue, it includes the installation guide

- [video Python](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfMk31VKxrY)
- [video xml](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCxYpofncKs)

Above will improve your experience to edit file faster!